# When is the sample median a good estimator of the population mean?

Tags: mean, median, estimators

Are there any practical cases or a general rule about this?

Comment: The median is more robust to outliers. If you observe extreme values on one side of the true mean then the sample mean will be more affected than the sample median.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question.

Answer (score 5):

As an aside, this depends on how you define a "good estimator".

---

Most simply, the sample median is a good estimator of the population mean when the population mean and population median are equal. If the population mean and population median are different, then the sample median estimates the population  median and will likely not do a good job of estimating the population mean.

For symmetric distributions, the population mean and population median are equal, so the sample median can be used to estimate the population mean. This will yield a more robust estimator compared to the sample mean.

Comment: Thank you. However, if the population is symmetric why not just use the mean, given that the mean is more efficient? In other words, why does robustness matter if the population is symmetric?

Comment: The mean is asymptotically more efficient (assuming that the mean is the MLE). Robustness matters in small sample sizes to have a safeguard against outliers.